# MySQL - Query to find student status of enrolment on different levels of courses

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, `students`, `enrolments` and `courses`. Any student can enrol in any course, and each course has a "level", from 1 (beginner) to 4 (advanced). I'm trying to find student information to check if a student is enrolled in a level 1/2/3/4 course. I'm trying to get student enrolment information result in the following manner:

## Result:

```
==================================================================
student_id | student_name | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4
==================================================================
324245       Rick Grimes     Yes        Yes        No       No
324912       Maggie Greene   Yes        Yes       Yes       No
```

The table structures are as follows:

## Structure:

students table

```
=============================================
student_id | name | email | school_id | grade
=============================================
```

courses table

```
==============================================================================
course_id | name | description | level | credits | course_starts | course_ends
==============================================================================
```

enrolments table

```
============================================
id | student_id | course_id | enrolment_date
============================================
```

Comment: Have you tried anything??What result did you get??If you post what you have tried we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.student_id,
        a.student_name,
        CASE WHEN SUM(c.level = 1) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END level_1,
        CASE WHEN SUM(c.level = 2) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END level_2,
        CASE WHEN SUM(c.level = 3) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END level_3,
        CASE WHEN SUM(c.level = 4) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END level_4
FROM    students a
        LEFT JOIN enrollments b
            ON a.student_id = b.student_id
        LEFT JOIN curses c
            ON b.course_id = c.course_ID
GROUP   BY a.student_id, a.student_name
```

You need to join first all the tables using `LEFT JOIN` since you want to show all students. This statement `SUM(c.level = 1)` counts all records where level is equal to 1, if the result is greater than 0, it means that the student has taken the course within the level.

Comment: I was trying something similar, except I missed `SUM()` and was getting errors. Still very new to the CASE WHEN syntax! Your answer works perfectly, thanks!